# Can one kafka consumer belong to multiple consumer groups?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Kafka, each consumer group is composed of many consumer instances for scalability and fault tolerance.

Can kafka consumer belong to multiple consumer groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot. There is only one `group.id` per consumer instance configuration